# CSS Selector to get the element attribute value

Tags: python, css-selectors, web-scraping, scrapy

The HTML structure is like this:

```
<td class='hey'> 
<a href="https://example.com">First one</a>
</td>
```

This is my selector:

```
m_URL = sel.css("td.hey a:nth-child(1)[href] ").extract()
```

My selector now will output `<a href="https://example.com">First one</a>`, but I only want it to output the link itself: `https://example.com`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Get the `::attr(value)` from the `a` tag.

Demo (using [Scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
>>> response.css('td.hey a:nth-child(1)::attr(href)').extract()
[u'https://example.com']
```

where `index.html` contains:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='hey'>
            <a href="https://example.com">Fist one</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

you may try this:

```
m_URL = sel.css("td.hey a:nth-child(1)").xpath('@href').extract()
```

Comment: so the css can't not do it ? Because I was wrote in xpath. And want to practice how to translate into css