# Get background-image or data-imageurl in <li>, its possible with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I need get only background-image or data-imageurl, its possible with scrapy?

```
'imagem': response.xpath('//li[@id="propertyImageSlide"]').extract()
```

"imagem": ["<li id="propertyImageSlide" **data-image="https://cdn.portugalproperty.com/images/made/property-images/170528/170528_38nwaa0b_1571143267_[size].jpg**" class="slide">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t"]}

Comment: <li id="propertyImageSlide" data-image="https://cdn.portugalproperty.com/images/made/property-images/170514/170514_qvo80yen_1570768500_[size].jpg" class="slide" style="height: 625px; width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1; background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.portugalproperty.com/images/made/property-images/170514/170514_qvo80yen_1570768500_720.jpg&quot;);">
</li>

Comment: If you are trying to get the `data-image` attribute value, please see if this is similar to what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987710/4476582 as well as the docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1

Answer (score 0):

```
'imagem': response.xpath('//li[@id="propertyImageSlide"]/@data-image').extract()

# A bit more pretty with CSS selectors instead of Xpath

'imagem': response.css('li#propertyImageSlide::attr(data-image)').extract()
```

Comment: hy, mychael 
thanks 

But i need get de background-image: 
the data-image has a _size string

<li id="propertyImageSlide" data-image="https://cdn.portugalproperty.com/images/made/property-images/171275/171275_bfgyzj3t_1589806121_[size].jpg" class="slide flex-active-slide" style="height: 625px; width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2; background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.portugalproperty.com/images/made/property-images/171275/171275_bfgyzj3t_1589806121_1080.jpg&quot;);"></li>